# The prefix "security" for element "security:http" is not bound

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-mvc, gwt-rpc

i get error

2009-05-24 21:49:56,399 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 38 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "security" for element "security:http" is not bound.

reference url: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=242557#post242557

can anyone please comment what i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You posted the question on the spring forum, and it was answered there.